# Matlab - Fuzzy k-Nearest Neighbor Classification Algorithm Example

Tags: algorithm, matlab, fuzzy, knn

I am searching for an example that implement FKNN, I found [this function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13358-fuzzy-k-nn)

as

```
function [predicted,memberships, numhits] = fknn(data, labels, test, ...
        testlabels, k_values, info, fuzzy)
```

But I cant call that function.. any example will be more than appreciated.

Comment: I am searching for that code but I can't find

Comment: %  [Y,MEMS,HITS] = FKNN(DATA, LABELS, TEST, TESTLABELS, K, INFO, FUZZY) If
%  you don't want to do "fuzzy" k-nn, then give FUZZY as 'false'.
%
% This m-file is capable of testing several k-values simultaneously. If
% you pass a vector of k-values, rather than a single scalar, in K, then
% each output variable is populated accordingly. So, if you give K as 
% [5 10 15], then Y becomes M-by-3, MEMS M-by-C-by-3 and HITS  3-by-1.